# how to make Main Activity thread affect Second Activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

My `MainActivity` has a `Thread` that generates RSA keys and returns the amount of time in milliseconds that it took to generate them.

While I run this `Thread`, the app goes to a second `Activity`.

I need the second `Activity` to receive that time in milliseconds.

As I understand, once you call `startActivity()`, the parent `Activity` goes to sleep. So how can I run both simultaneously?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a broadcast receiver to notify who even listens that your RAS keys are there.

Comment: thanks! i'll look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I understand, once you startActivity(), the parent activity goes to sleep. So how can I run both simultaneously

You do not. And you do not need to. Since you generate your RSA keys on a separate thread that code should be **fully** independent from your activities (aside from being started in `MainActivity`). So all you need to know is when your background task finished - and for that you can use either in-app [broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) or use Event Bus like [GreenRobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library or use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava).

Comment: Thank you! I'll start researching broadcasts!

Answer (score 1):

You can use LocalBroadcastReceiver.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BroadcastReceiver mRsaReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ArrayList<String> rsaList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("rsaList");
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRsaReceiver, new IntentFilter("RSA"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRsaReceiver);
}
```

}

From Your rsa thread

```
Intent rsaIntent = new Intent("RSA");
rsaIntent.putExtra("rsaList", rsaArrayList);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(rsaIntent);
```